# Possible to delete nodes on new page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, greasemonkey

When clicking "Slow Download" on [this](http://nitroflare.com/view/A71F0994E20F2E0/security-privacy.jpg) page it gives an overlay modal which covers the screen with id's `superbox-wrapper` and `superbox-overlay`. I can remove them in Chrome developer tools by just deleting them.

Right now I have the follow code which clicks on the "Slow Download" button.

```
function SkipId(objId){
    var oId = document.getElementById(objId);
    oId.click();
}

window.onload = function(){
    SkipId('slow-download');
};
```

I have tried to remove them by

```
document.getElementById('superbox-wrapper').hide();
document.getElementById('superbox-overlay').hide();

var element = document.getElementById("superbox-wrapper");
element.outerHTML = "";
delete element;

function remove(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    return elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}

remove('superbox-wrapper');

getElementById('superbox-wrapper').remove();
```

**Question**

How can I remove `superbox-wrapper` and `superbox-overlay`?

Comment: This is a common problem (but don't have a dupe-hammer target yet).  Lookup `waitForKeyElements` (easy) or `MutationObserver` (raw).

Comment: @BrockAdams - MutationObserver wont work since the page is reloaded with these elements already in the DOM.

Comment: @Skav, When using the `MutationObserver` technique, typically a check for preexisting elements is also run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Brock Adams comment this this the solution

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @require https://greasyfork.org/scripts/5392-waitforkeyelements/code/WaitForKeyElements.js?version=115012

waitForKeyElements("div.superbox-wrapper", removeSuperbox);

function removeSuperbox() {
  document.getElementById('superbox-wrapper').hide();
}
```

Comment: The code should actually be: `function removeSuperbox(jNode) { jNode.hide(); }`

Answer (score -1):

After getting the elements you can use their parent's `removeChild` function to remove the elements, like this:

```js
                       
let overlay = document.getElementById("superbox-overlay");
let wrapper = document.getElementById("superbox-wrapper");

if( overlay ){
    overlay.parentElement.removeChild( overlay );
}

if( wrapper ){
    wrapper.parentElement.removeChild( wrapper );
}
```

Comment: THIS DOES NOT WORK. For the same reason that the OP's code did not work.  This is a userscript scenario and the elements in question are added via AJAX long, long, after the userscript runs.

Comment: @BrockAdams - The elements do not load with an AJAX request,  Clicking on the 'Slow Download' button forces a full page reload with the elements in question already loaded.  The script above in tampermonkey ensures the popup is removed.

Comment: Did you find and test the OP's actual page? If so, link? Also, if the your code works, then the OP's `document.getElementById('superbox-wrapper').hide()` should've also worked.  Both codes will work from the console but not from a userscript (most likely).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "we're good".  If your code works on the actual page (link please), **in a userscript**, I can remove my downvote.